# 3 phase fully controlled rectifier

Tags: power-electronics, converter, thyristor

A 3 phase fully controlled bridge converter is fed through star-delta transformer. The converter is operated at a firing angle of 30 degrees. Assuming the load to be a RL load and load current to be virtually constant at 1 pu and transformer to be an ideal one, how will be the input phase current waveform look like ?

**Edit:**

[image]

I was expecting the following result

[image]

but to my surprise the answer is the following waveform.

[image]

Definitely I'm making some mistake, please tell me how the waveform came.

Comment: This has a very strong smell of homework with no attempt at solving. Show your work and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Can you start by providing a schematic? (I *love* schematics!)

Comment: This was not a homework, but yes I was unable to get the answer.